# ScaleToFit does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have problems with the ScaletoFit method. I Have a UIPageViewController with a UIImagesView and want to show different pictures in it, but it does not work as it should.

With these two lines I initialize the picture.

```
self.screenPicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
self.screenPicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

it's build in a case structure, which decides what picture the user can see.

```
switch(self.index)
    {
        case zero: {
            self.screenNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.", nil];
            self.screenPicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
            self.screenPicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
            break;
        }
        case one: {
            self.screenNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2.", nil];
            self.screenPicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
            self.screenPicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
            break;
        }
        case two: {
            self.screenNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3.", nil];
            self.screenPicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
            self.screenPicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
            break;
        }
        case three: {
            self.screenNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"4.", nil];
            self.screenPicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"];
            self.screenPicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            self.screenNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5.", nil];
            self.screenPicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
            self.screenPicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
            break;
        }
    }
```

In the App the picture is now in the original size, which is too big.
Why is the `ScaleAspectFit`-Method not working?

can somebody help me?

Thanks:)

Comment: The question is: Why does the ScaleAspectFit-Method not work?

Comment: You need to reword this question. I doesn't make sense.

Comment: insert a Log message and see if the code is actually executed. It seems that this piece of code has never being executed and aspectFit has never being applied to your imageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode):

> The content mode specifies how the cached bitmap of the view’s layer is adjusted when the view’s bounds change.

...and not the other way around. You seem to want to resize the view based on its content, but `contentMode` does the opposite.

Comment: so you mean i resized the UIImageView and not the Image? wtf?

Comment: Kinda. I don't see that you set a size for the UIImageView anywhere, so it probably just assumed the size if the image automatically. In order to get the image resized to the size of your UIImageView, you will need to set a size for the UIImageView. Then your code will adjust the image size accordingly, as you've set it. You can use autolayout or just set a specific frame for your UIImageView, depending on your requirements.

Comment: you mean like UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 198, 380)]; ? Doesn't work, either!

Comment: This code won't work if you have Autolayout enabled. You have to disable Autolayout or (recommended) leave it enabled, and use it :) and set the layout constraints for your UIImageView as you want them. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html